# The entity data model designer is unable to to display the file your requested

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, ado.net, npgsql

While opeing edmx file in visual stuido 2019 -- The entity data model designer is unable to to display the file your requested.

**Errorwhich is showing in error list**- The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'Npgsql' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.

Comment: Show me the inner exception

Comment: Try this Nuget library to simplify Ado.net code  : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ado.Entity